# Strange behavior with `find -delete`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, bash, ext4

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with 2 x 2TB SATA3 harddisks in software RAID1. The filesystem is ext4 with `data=writeback`.

When using `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -delete` to delete a large number of files in a directory, doing `df` at intervals show that:

**Initially** a large number of files get deleted, and `iotop` shows the `find` operation taking most of the IO.

[image]

**Later** `df` shows that the number of files remain constant, and `iotop` shows that IO usage is now dominated by `jbd2` and `md4_raid1`.

[image]

**Few minutes later**, `df` shows the number of files dropping once more.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Is this normal or is there something wrong with my server? Also, how can 3 processes all have 99.99% IO usage at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

It's what I would expect. Find finds files - i.e. it reads from the VFS, when the data is not in cache it needs to be fetched from disk. As it processes each file, it enqueues the changes to be written. At some point the write buffer gets full and the changes must be written to the disk - at this point the process doing the writes will be blocked making further write OR READ requests until there's space to buffer more writes.

Comment: When this mass deleting is done, the server slows to an almost complete halt. Is there a way for the server to avoid getting thrashed by the write block?

Comment: Don't delete so many files all at once?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/487599/running-a-process-within-a-limited-amount-of-resources-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the system from being blocked by reducing the I/O priority of the process:

```
ionice -c3 nice -15 find ... -delete
```

If that's not enough then you can use chrt to put the process into the SCHED_IDLE class.

Comment: Should I actually reduce the IO priority of `[jbd2/*]` and `[md4_raid1]`? Will that slow down my entire IO subsystem even more?

Comment: Don't touch that kernel stuff. I even doubt that it's possible to change their priority anyway.